# Error in creating the CFNCluster-fails at creating Comuptenodes

Tags: amazon-ec2, cluster-computing

I am trying to create CFN cluster with the below command but it fails to intiate the  compute nodes.

```
cfncluster create cfnclustertest
```

if i set the "InitialQueueSize" to 0 in my config file i am able to create the cluster successfully but not able to run/submit jobs on the cluster.
but if i set the initial queue size =2(default) cluster creation fails at computefleet.

please find the errow log below:

```
01:21:52 UTC+0550   CREATE_FAILED   AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  cfncluster-cfnclustertest3  The following resource(s) failed to create: [ComputeFleet].
01:21:51 UTC+0550   CREATE_FAILED   AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup  ComputeFleet    Received FAILURE signal with UniqueId i-507761cd
Physical ID:cfncluster-cfnclustertest3-ComputeFleet-1JYYYNR7Q1XDI
01:15:59 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup  ComputeFleet    Resource creation Initiated
Physical ID:cfncluster-cfnclustertest3-ComputeFleet-1JYYYNR7Q1XDI
01:15:59 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup  ComputeFleet    
01:15:51 UTC+0550   CREATE_COMPLETE AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration   ComputeServerLaunchConfig   
Physical ID:cfncluster-cfnclustertest3-ComputeServerLaunchConfig-SSUNR2V5VD9N
01:15:51 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration   ComputeServerLaunchConfig   Resource creation Initiated
01:15:50 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration   ComputeServerLaunchConfig   
01:15:40 UTC+0550   CREATE_COMPLETE AWS::EC2::Instance  MasterServer    
01:15:38 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::Instance  MasterServer    Received SUCCESS signal with UniqueId i-e94d5b74
01:09:10 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::Instance  MasterServer    Resource creation Initiated
01:09:07 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::Instance  MasterServer    
01:08:57 UTC+0550   CREATE_COMPLETE AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile   RootInstanceProfile 
01:06:57 UTC+0550   CREATE_COMPLETE AWS::IAM::Policy    CfnClusterPolicies  
01:06:57 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::IAM::Policy    CfnClusterPolicies  Resource creation Initiated
01:06:56 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile   RootInstanceProfile Resource creation Initiated
01:06:56 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile   RootInstanceProfile 
01:06:55 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::IAM::Policy    CfnClusterPolicies  
01:06:49 UTC+0550   CREATE_COMPLETE AWS::IAM::Role  RootRole    
01:06:45 UTC+0550   CREATE_COMPLETE AWS::EC2::EIPAssociation    AssosiateEIP    
01:06:29 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::EIPAssociation    AssosiateEIP    Resource creation Initiated

01:06:29 UTC+0550   CREATE_COMPLETE AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress  MasterSecurityGroupIngress  
01:06:28 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::EIPAssociation    AssosiateEIP    
01:06:28 UTC+0550   CREATE_COMPLETE AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress  ComputeSecurityGroupIngress 
01:06:28 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress  MasterSecurityGroupIngress  Resource creation Initiated
01:06:28 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress  MasterSecurityGroupIngress  
01:06:27 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress  ComputeSecurityGroupIngress Resource creation Initiated
01:06:27 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress  ComputeSecurityGroupIngress 
01:06:20 UTC+0550   CREATE_COMPLETE AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface  MasterENI   
01:06:20 UTC+0550   CREATE_COMPLETE AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup ComputeSecurityGroup    
01:06:18 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup ComputeSecurityGroup    Resource creation Initiated
01:06:18 UTC+0550   CREATE_COMPLETE AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy   SQSPolicy   
01:06:17 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy   SQSPolicy   Resource creation Initiated
01:06:17 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy   SQSPolicy   
01:06:14 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::IAM::Role  RootRole    Resource creation Initiated
01:06:10 UTC+0550   CREATE_COMPLETE AWS::DynamoDB::Table    DynamoDBTable   
01:06:04 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface  MasterENI   Resource creation Initiated
01:06:03 UTC+0550   CREATE_COMPLETE AWS::SNS::Topic SNS 
01:06:03 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface  MasterENI   
01:06:03 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup ComputeSecurityGroup    
01:05:57 UTC+0550   CREATE_COMPLETE AWS::EC2::EIP   MasterEIP   
01:05:56 UTC+0550   CREATE_COMPLETE AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup MasterSecurityGroup 
01:05:55 UTC+0550   CREATE_COMPLETE AWS::EC2::Volume    SharedVolume    
01:05:54 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup MasterSecurityGroup Resource creation Initiated
01:05:52 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::SNS::Topic SNS Resource creation Initiated
01:05:52 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::SNS::Topic SNS 
01:05:44 UTC+0550   CREATE_COMPLETE AWS::SQS::Queue SQS 
01:05:43 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::SQS::Queue SQS Resource creation Initiated
01:05:41 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::EIP   MasterEIP   Resource creation Initiated
01:05:40 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::EIP   MasterEIP   
01:05:40 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::SQS::Queue SQS 
01:05:39 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::DynamoDB::Table    DynamoDBTable   Resource creation Initiated
01:05:38 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::DynamoDB::Table    DynamoDBTable   
01:05:38 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::Volume    SharedVolume    Resource creation Initiated
01:05:38 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup MasterSecurityGroup 
01:05:38 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::IAM::Role  RootRole    
01:05:37 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::Volume    SharedVolume    
01:05:27 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  cfncluster-cfnclustertest3  User Initiated
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was answered in the AWS HPC forums - [forum post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=232003&tstart=0). The issue was related to VPC DNS settings.